# Check if Image is in Cache - Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I guess the title says it all. I tried:

```
imageLoader.getMemoryCache().get(key);
```

with the image uri as key, but it always return `null`

although I enabled caching in the config.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `MemoryCacheUtils`.

```
MemoryCacheUtils.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

Memory cache can contain several bitmaps (diffenrent sizes) for one image. So memory cache use special keys, not image urls.

Comment: @NOSTRA this is not working for me. If I use:

MemoryCacheUtil.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(url, ImageLoader.getInstance());

it asks me for casting, so... is this correct?

                MemoryCacheUtil.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(url, (MemoryCacheAware<String, Bitmap>) ImageLoader.getInstance());

Comment: @NOSTRA, why using this code
MemoryCacheUtil.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
returns an arraylist of bitmap? and getting the first value in arraylist returns random bitmap? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because memory cache can contain different sizes (Bitmaps) of the same image. Actually you can deny it in configuration.

Comment: @NOSTRA , can u plz take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480098/make-cache-images-to-appear-in-gallery-while-using-uinversal-image-loader-in-and

Answer (score 2):

It should be MemoryCacheUtil**s**, so you should use

```
MemoryCacheUtils.findCachedBitmapsForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
```

Answer (score 2):

For disk cache use below code

```
public static boolean isDiskCache(String url) {
        File file = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
        return file != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when using the Universal Image Loader library, there comes a time where the loader takes a while to verify whether the remote image has been already loaded in your cache. To load the cache file directly, you can use the following method to check whether a local copy of the remote file has already been made:

```
    File file = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(url);  
 if (!file.exists()) {  
      DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()  
      .cacheOnDisc()  
      .build();  
      imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);  
 }  
 else {  
      imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));  
 }
```

check it here[enter link description here](http://cbpbenitez.blogspot.com/2013/11/access-cache-file-on-universal-image.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a simple method in your utility class like this:

```
public static boolean isImageAvailableInCache(String imageUrl){
    MemoryCache memoryCache = ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache();
    if(memoryCache!=null) {
        for (String key : memoryCache.keys()) {
            if (key.startsWith(imageUrl)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and Use it like:

```
   if(Utils.isImageAvailableInCache(imageUrl)){
//
      }
```